# Is there a way to store a users password safely but be able to access that password to authenticate an API?

Tags: web-services, security, passwords, password-protection

I would like to have a service that stores a users password safely while also allowing my code to retrieve that password and authenticate the user for an external API. Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: You would not retreive the users password but an access token, look into OAuth2

Comment: when do you need to have the password? at any time or only when user is logged in?

Comment: It is a service that runs in the background. So at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is the following:

1. Take the clear text password
2. Use a salt
3. Hash the password and the salt using SHA-1 or similar hashing algorithm
4. Store that hash as the password into a datastore

When the user then authenticates redo step 1-3 and instead of store the password in the datastore, compare it to the hash in the datastore, if you have a match, then the password is correct.

OR, have the user sign up and get a "passkey" which is a random sequence of characters, have him/her hash it once (no salt) and send it to your API, then rehash it with the salt and compare that.

It all depends on how sensitive it is.

//JaggenSWE

Comment: The thing is I need their exact password for the external API. My service will run in the background and send them notifications on certain conditions. They can't be logging in all the time.

Comment: @edhedges As soon as you allow the users password to be used by an external service it is no longer safe and secure

Comment: But do you actually have to have the password stored as clear text?

Comment: Otherwise, just generate a token (guid or similar) and use that for the communication within the "session". Put a timestamp on it so it rots if no activity is monitored within a specific period of time. That way you only send the password/hash once and then use the token to "reauthenticate" calls.

Comment: Yes that is why I am having trouble seeing if this would even work.

Comment: If you need to actually handle the password in clear text, enrypt it. Use AES with a nice long random key, a nice long random salt and a decent IV, that way you could encrypt and decrypt it as you wish.

Comment: @edhedges Though if I were to ever use a site that you made where you are storing my password in clear text form then let me know now so I can delete my account!

Comment: @Sammaye Yes I know. That is why I posed the question. To see how other people have done. I may just do a pull request because the external API is open source and some may want the feature I am proposing with my service.

Comment: Still I really don't see the big issue. Encryption and hashing and the security issues would be almost mitigated. Have the API behind SSL or similar if traffic is going over internet. Clear text passwords are never a good idea, in any system, which has been proven time and time again. Make the user "login" using their password or a simple hash. Return a token which has limited lifespan (like a cookie), use the token for all other communications with that users system. On your end, rehash or encrypt/decrypt the passwords and the token to verify it's legit and hey presto, should work.

Comment: @JaggenSWE I just don't like the fact that I would have access to their passwords by decrypting the encrypted passwords in my database. I myself wouldn't go and mess with their things, but I wouldn't trust a service like that.

Comment: @edhedges I would use the OAuth2 system, it is used by Twitter, Facebook, Google and many others, look into it you won't be disapointed by its features. Plus it is simpler than building something of your own from scratch that might have a serious flaw in it, JaggenSWE does make a good point but still I would rather use something thats proven

Comment: @edhedges In fact JaggenSWE's latst reply is basically simple OAuth

Comment: I've voted to close the question because my initial thoughts were confirmed.